# Java - путь исполняемого jar файла

Tags: java, jar

Требуется достать полный путь исполняемого файла, но при этом вернуться на 1 каталог назад, к примеру

```
мой класс.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()
```

Возвращает

```
/C:/Users/Arturs/Desktop/DIV.jar
```

но мне нужно довести до `/C:/Users/Arturs/`
Есть ли какие то предусмотренные функции, что бы не приходилось обрезать строку, высчитывая количество символов справа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
    Path path = Paths.get(твой_класс.class.getResource(".").toURI());
    System.out.println(path.getParent());               // <-- Parent directory
    System.out.println(path.getParent().getParent());   // <-- Parent of parent directory
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно это и нужно было )

Comment: Только что-то после упаковки в исполняемый jar ничего не работает.

Comment: @Artik можете задать как новый вопрос и мы вам поможем.

Comment: Та я уже задавал. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558269/%d0%9f%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%83-%d0%b2-ubuntu/558270

Answer (score 7):

Попробуй

```
new File(мой класс.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()).getParent();
```

Comment: у `getPath()` нет метода `getParent()`

Comment: см update ответа